# What is the purpose of ChaincodeBase.start() in dev mode [java]?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I'm still trying to make sense of all moving pieces. After standing up a network via docker-compose with dev mode enabled I can build and run Fabric examples. From my remote workstation I can run e.g. this example https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/java/SimpleSample/src/main/java/example/SimpleSample.java

and point it to this dev network. The code communicates and registers the codechain, but then there's a thread which keeps running on the client (killing it would unregister the codechain).

What would be the next steps to interact with this codechain from the 'cli' container? I was looking at instructions here: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/JAVAChaincode.html , but they don't make sense. There's not even the -l switch available in the 1.0.0-rc1 version of the images.

Could someone please explain the full cycle of how deploy/invoke would work from here?

Answer (score 0):

Start() is always called (dev mode or not) to start the chaincode. The only difference between dev mode and non-dev mode is that in the former user starts the chaincode pointing to the server to register with while in the later the fabric spins up the server.

You would "instantiate" in dev mode too so the "init" method can be called with appropriate args. The Start will only "register" the chaincode with the fabric side.